# Communicating between two threads without wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lock-free

I am working on a piece of code, where I need to communicate between two threads. The catch is that one thread cannot wait in locks. Let me explain the scenario in more detail:

I am running a simulation, where some entities are created in the simulation and updates its states within that simulation. On the other hand, the state of the entity is rendered in a rendering engine.

My application is a rendering frame work, that initialises rendering context and is also responsible for starting a new simulation thread.

Now I need to design code that creates the corresponding screne object(s) in the scene graph. As a part of that, I will need to inform the rendering engine when the simulation created all the entities. Once the rendering engine creates the scene objects, the simulation thread needs to update the position and orientation on the scene object in rendering engine.

So, currently, the simulation engine has a mechanism to register observers for different event (object created, deleted or moved) and can call callbacks when these events are triggered.

I need to design code that would allow something like as follows:

```
RENDERER                          SIMULATION
=========                        ============
Application starts
    |
Render context initialised
    |
    |----------------------------> Create simulation thread
    |                                   |
    |                               Created simulation objects
    |                                   |
    |<----- message objects created-----|
    |                                   |
 Created scene objects                  |                  
 based on simulation objects            |
    |                                   |
    |---notify scene objects created -> |
    |                                   |
    | <----- update scene objects ------|
    |
 Render updated states
```

One of the suggestion to achieve this behaviour is to use shared container.

When the simulation engine creates all the entities, it populates a list with those objects. The rendering engine can read the container and creates corresponding scene objects. Once the scene objects are created, the rendering engine populates a shared container with the object pointers. The simulation engine can then update the state of the scene objects.

Now, I am not quite sure what is the best way to achieve this. One thing is certain, if I am using shared container, the thread cannot wait for other threads to complete writing. If the rendering thread checks the shared container and it is not empty, it will just ignore and will continue rendering. At the same time, if the simulation thread found that no scene object is created, it will just ignore and continue on simulation loop.

I am using Boost Thread. Any suggestion on the design?

Comment: Interesting that you want use multiple threads. If I read your explanation, I see a lot of "after ... then ..." This looks like a full linear algorithm. Maybe you can render things in parallel, but this is a fully other design...

Comment: Well may be my wording gave you a wrong impression. In actual design, simulation loop and rendering loop run in parallel. I was just describing the different stages of communication between them using after ... then. irrespective of the state of simulation engine, my rendering thread continues rendering. only it doesn't have any information from simulation layer.

Comment: "Once the rendering engine creates the scene objects, the simulation thread needs to update the position and orientation on the scene object in rendering engine." - this sounds like a very bad idea: it violates the separation of concerns and leads to a lot of shared sthate.

Comment: Creating lock-free design for non-very-simple project is mostly state of art, so it is "too broad" for Stack Overflow. From the other side, you already have very descriptive design. Just start to implement it, and ask about **specific problems** you encounter.